# Do I need to refresh the sqlalchemy connection object to be able to insert data to newly created table?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pymysql

I am a beginner in sqlalchemy.

My connection function in **`_core.py`**

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from methodtools import lru_cache


@lru_cache(maxsize=16)
def get_engine(db="homelan"):
    qs = 'mysql+pymysql://user:pwd@localhost/{db}'.format(db=db)
    engine = create_engine(qs)
    connection = engine.connect()
    return engine, connection
```

in my code if the table does not exist for a specific host machine I create. as shown below:

**`server_status.py`**

```
class HostStatusManager(object):

    keep_record = 10 # days

    """This class contains methods to manage the status of the host
    registered in database for supervision or monitoring purpose.
    """

    def __init__(self, ip_address):
        super(HostStatusManager, self).__init__()
        self._ip = ip_address
        engine, connection = _core.get_engine()
        self._engine = engine
        self._connection = connection
        self._host_table = None
        self._host_table_name = None
        if not self.host_status_table_exists():
            self._host_table = self._create_table()



    def get_status(self):
        """Gets the latest status of the host whether online or offline.
        """
        columns = self._host_table.columns
        print("Cols: ".format(columns))
        select_field = getattr(columns, "status")
        query = db.select(
                [select_field]
            ).order_by(
                db.desc(
                    getattr(columns, "id")
                    )
                ).limit(1)
        _log.debug(query)
        ResultProxy = self._connection.execute(query)
        ResultSet = ResultProxy.fetchall()
        if ResultSet:
            return ResultSet[0][0]
        _log.warning("No existing status found from {0}.".format(
            self._host_table
            )
        )

    def set_status(self, data):
        query = db.insert(self._host_table).values(**data)
        results = self._connection.execute(query)
```

If I directly call `set_status` it works fine but the `get_status` throws error saying:

> pymysql.err.InternalError: (1412, 'Table definition has changed,
>   please retry transaction')

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using an lru cache to store connections, but rather use the engine's built in connection pool. Then, every time you need to talk to the database, ask for a connection from the engine, and close the connection when you're done with it. The engine will by default have a pool of size 5.

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

def get_engine(db="homelan"):
    qs = 'mysql+pymysql://user:pwd@localhost/{db}'.format(db=db)
    engine = create_engine(qs)
    return engine
```

```py
class HostStatusManager(object):

    keep_record = 10 # days

    """This class contains methods to manage the status of the host
    registered in database for supervision or monitoring purpose.
    """

    def __init__(self, ip_address):
        super(HostStatusManager, self).__init__()
        self._ip = ip_address
        engine, connection = _core.get_engine()
        self._engine = engine
        self._host_table = None
        self._host_table_name = None
        if not self.host_status_table_exists():
            self._host_table = self._create_table()



    def get_status(self):
        """Gets the latest status of the host whether online or offline.
        """
        columns = self._host_table.columns
        print("Cols: ".format(columns))
        select_field = getattr(columns, "status")
        query = db.select(
                [select_field]
            ).order_by(
                db.desc(
                    getattr(columns, "id")
                    )
                ).limit(1)
        _log.debug(query)
        connection = self._engine.connect()
        try:
            ResultProxy = connection.execute(query)
            ResultSet = ResultProxy.fetchall()
            if ResultSet:
                return ResultSet[0][0]
            _log.warning("No existing status found from {0}.".format(
                self._host_table
                )
            )
        finally:
            connection.close()

    def set_status(self, data):
        query = db.insert(self._host_table).values(**data)
        connection = self._engine.connect()
        try:
            results = connection.execute(query)
        finally:
            connection.close()
```

Comment: instead of handling with try should I re call the `connection = self._engine.get_connection()` right after new table is created ?

Comment: PS: I tried : `connection = self._engine.get_connection()` and got this error
> AttributeError: 'Engine' object has no attribute 'get_connection'

Comment: Sorry, engine.connect(). I'll fix it.

Comment: thanks used that already, also try block cannot be without except.

Comment: you said default pool size is 5, does that mean for an existing connection it is limited to 5 transactions only unless closed ?

Comment: It means you can have five concurrent connections open to the database at once.

Comment: I see that means it could be from different instance of engine.